# Copying myself on a workflow answer reply

Tags: javascript

I am creating a workflow script that works well except for one hiccup. When the approver clicks approve or deny, I am supposed to be copied on their answer. I've tried dozens of ways and still can't get it to work properly. See code below:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  var req = e.values[1];
  var reqfor = e.values[2];
  var reqforemail = e.values[3];
  var location = e.values[8];
  var reqbyemail = e.values[10];
  var director = e.values[13];
  var copyon = e.values[14];  

  var url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/ehdtech.com/s/AKfycbw1AqqDzH_sluzpbTo9ekbVX0e2k7E3Y-JNuD6IZuADvyzYRTTt/exec';

  var approve = url + '?approval=true'+'&reply='+reqbyemail;
  var reject = url + '?approval=false'+'&reply='+reqbyemail;


  var html = "<body>"+
                 "<h2>Please Review</h2><br />"+
                   "A computer or email address request form has been submitted by user: "+ reqbyemail+ "<br />"+
                     "For either an email address, computer or both indicated here: "+ req+ "<br />"+
                     "To be utilized at this locaton: "+ location+ "<br />"+
                     "The computer or email address will be issued to: "+ reqfor+ "<br />"+
                     "Their email address is or will be: "+reqforemail+ "<br />"+
                     "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
                     "<a href="+ reject +">Reject</a><br />"+
                  "</body>";
 MailApp.sendEmail(director,"Approval Request",
                   "What no html?", {htmlBody: html});
}

  function doGet(e){ 

    var answer = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Computer or email assignment approved. Your request is being fulfilled.' : 'This computer or email request has been rejected, for more information contact your director';


    MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.copyon, "Computer Request","","Your manager said: "+ answer);
    MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply,"Computer Request","","Your manager said: "+ answer);

    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>An email was sent to '+ e.parameter.reply + ' and jami.schmohe@ehdtech.com saying: '+ answer + '</h2>'))
    return app       
  }
```

col 1  what was requested,
col 2  the new employee receiving the computer,
col 3  new employee email,
col 8  the location the computer will reside,
col 10  email address of requester,
col 13  email address or director,
col 14  my email address,